# Hiding block when the next sibiling is empty with XSL-FO

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm using Apache FOP to generate reports, my template's like this:

```
<xsl:template match="LOGO">
    <xsl:param name="imgLogo">
        <xsl:value-of select="IMG" />
    </xsl:param>
    <fo:external-graphic content-height="scale-to-fit"
        height="50pt" src="{$imgLogo}" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MYREPORT">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="LOGO" />
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="PAG_1" />
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block page-break-before="always">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="LOGO" />
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="PAG_2" />
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block page-break-before="always">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="LOGO" />
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="PAG_3" />
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

I've to hide the "LOGO" block (before each PAGE) if the next sibiling block (PAGE) is empty.

For example, with the following input:

```
<MYREPORT>
  <LOGO>
    <IMG>data:image/png;base64,[cutted]</IMG>
  </LOGO>
  <PAG_1>Page 1</PAG_1>
  <PAG_2>Page 2</PAG_2>
</MYREPORT>
```

It should print:

```
LOGO
Page 1
(new page)
LOGO
Page 2
```

It's printing the following instead:

```
LOGO
Page 1
(new page)
LOGO
Page 2
(new page)
LOGO
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Just FYI. This question is purely XSL and has nothing to do with XSL FO.

Comment: Just FYI. This question is purely XSL and has nothing to do with XSL FO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most direct way is to put an `xsl:if` around the code for `PAG_3`:

```
<xsl:template match="MYREPORT">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="LOGO" />
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="PAG_1" />
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block page-break-before="always">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="LOGO" />
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="PAG_2" />
    </fo:block>
    <xsl:if test="PAG_3">
      <fo:block page-break-before="always">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="LOGO" />
      </fo:block>
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="PAG_3" />
      </fo:block>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

An alternative approach (which I would use) is to use `xsl:apply-templates` to select the PAG_* elements so that a result is generated only for elements that exist:

```
<xsl:template match="MYREPORT">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="PAG_1 | PAG_2 | PAG_3" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PAG_1 | PAG_2 | PAG_3">
  <fo:block>
    <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
      <xsl:attribute name="page-break-before">always</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../LOGO" />
  </fo:block>
  <fo:block>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It's a kind of magic for me, but that's just what I was looking for... thank you!

Comment: Using `xsl:apply-templates` makes it easier to use the structure of the source document determine the result. It's often simpler than trying to predict the structure of every possible source document (as you found out). Any good introduction to XSLT will show you how to use `xsl:apply-templates` and multiple template rules rather than trying to do everything in one template. (I also changed the `xsl:value-of` in my second example to `xsl:apply-templates`: if `PAG_1` etc., every have any inline elements, the `xsl:value-of` would only have got you their string value.)